# keypress event in android

Tags: android

when i press the only  character button a to z to perform some action in android what is key ascii code for a to z can anybody tell  how to do in android?

Comment: If you get keycode, i think, it's 29 for a, and 50 for z, and 59 for A..... I want you to cross check it also

Answer (score 3):

here is the whole list of keycodes on android. Don't use the int. Use the static value of KeyEvent. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

in the activity you can overwrite one of the following (or more if you like)

```
boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event)
boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

and in there you can just do:

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A) {
    // do whatever you want.
}
```

instead of KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A use whatever you want. For example KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK for the back key.