# How to track the keys pressed in soft keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

How can I track the keys pressed by the user in keyboard in android?
Is this possible or I have to create a keyboard myself? 
What could be the possible way ?

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4212737/2345913)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen the keypress in the soft keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616567/how-to-listen-the-keypress-in-the-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [Creating An Input Method](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html). This would help you in creating a custom Input Method. You can check the Sample Application in your Android SDK directory. Please follow as per this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/samples/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

One way to liste for those is:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Log the Key that was pressed or do whatever you need
        // keyCode contains all the possible keyCode presses
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1){
        //You can insert catches for each particular keypress here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

All the codes are here in this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), take a look at them.

Comment: wrks only for Hardwr keybrd